# How do I divide one data.table by another in R, columnwise?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following:

```
data(cars)
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(cars)
B <- data.table(speed = 10, dist = 100)
```

I would like to divide the first column of A by the first element in B and the second column of A by the second element in B. So: `A[,1]/B[,1]` , `A[,2]/B[,2]`, ... The output should look like:

```
      speed    dist
 1:     0.4   0.02
 2:     0.4   0.10
 3:     0.7   0.04
 4:     0.7   0.22
        ...
```

(This is a toy example. I'm hoping to turn it into a function I can run over different datasets.)

Comment: Might be another option for you: `A / as.list(B)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map`

```
library(data.table)
A[, Map(`/`, .SD, B)]
#    speed dist
# 1:   0.4 0.02
# 2:   0.4 0.10
# 3:   0.7 0.04
# 4:   0.7 0.22
# 5:   0.8 0.16
```

Answer (score 1):

`akrun`'s `data.table` solution looks good. Here I offer an alternative, which does not require any library.

```
> do.call("rbind", apply(A, 1, function(x) x / B))
```

```
    speed dist
 1:   0.4 0.02
 2:   0.4 0.10
 3:   0.7 0.04
 4:   0.7 0.22
 5:   0.8 0.16
```

Comment: If I make a suggestion, in `base R`, you could also do this in a vectorized way with `t(t(A)/unlist(B))`

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks @akrun

Comment: Neat. Can you get `sweep()` to work? I can't. `sweep(A, 2, ...?)` See [R: apply with a division](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-July/166750.html)

Comment: Certainly **don't** do this. This is converting a data.table to a matrix and then runs a loop **per row** and then rbinds all the results. The fact that this doesn't use any "library" doesn't justify a very inefficient/unsafe and convoluted operation. If one wants to avoid "libraries", they can do it very efficiently in base R, e.g. see [markus comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746176/how-do-i-divide-one-data-table-by-another-in-r-columnwise#comment110960307_62746176)

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate the rows in shorter dataframe to match with longer dataframe and directly divide.

```
library(data.table)
A/B[rep(1, nrow(A))]

#    speed dist
# 1:   0.4 0.02
# 2:   0.4 0.10
# 3:   0.7 0.04
# 4:   0.7 0.22
# 5:   0.8 0.16
# 6:   0.9 0.10
# 7:   1.0 0.18
# 8:   1.0 0.26
# 9:   1.0 0.34
#10:   1.1 0.17
#.....
```